# Contest rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

This edit of mine got rejected today:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7062320

The reason given was "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.", which is funny because it makes no sense to me.

As far as I'm concerned, the edit was a genuine attempt to improve the post. And given the diff, I simply cannot comprehend how someone (let alone three reviewers) would suspect my being deliberately defacing the post, or promoting a product...

Is there any means to contest such cases?

Comment: The reviewers were probably intimidated by all the splotches of color in the diff.

Comment: The only questionable change that I see is changing "variable" to "value" as being potentially a semantic change, although without domain knowledge, I can't say conclusively.

Comment: @Servy I changed this because the parenthesis contains "SEs" and the user wants to get a "p-values" instead. In this context, it makes little sense to call this... value a "variable", and "value" is a more neutral and appropriate choice of vocabulary... It could also be the *value* of a "t-test". Also, the title as it is is simply not helpful for other users, and that little deserved a revamp...

Comment: It is possible that the reviewers made a snap judgement that this was an audit.  Also, your edit suggestion could really use a much better summary.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Yeah, a better summary may have been in order. But I didn't anticipate that the edit would prove contentious...

Comment: I don't agree with the rejection; in particular, the reason. Though, generally speaking, changing the semantics of questions doesn't resinate with those that might otherwise raise them. Also, is **SEs** shorthand for Standard Errors? That seems a bit too lingo to me...

Comment: Worth to mention that nothing can be done with this specific review: rejected edit can't be approved, best we can do is invite all three rejectors to see this meta post so they won't repeat same mistake again with other reviews.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yes, Standard Errors. For those reading the question, in the context of stargazer and linear models, this should be self-explanatory in most cases. But it doesn't hurt to insert to insert the long version in the question...

Comment: Looks to me like they tacked on to the "I love Stargazer" right at the front, although it was (obscurely) already in the original question, and interpreted that as a promotional message.  Removing or rephrasing it would actually improve the question, too (seems somebody already did); but if my conjecture is correct, that was a sloppy review by the auditors.

Comment: Good edit, landroni. Poor reviewing. Too many people don't take the time to understand when reviewing.

Answer (score 22):

> Is there any means to contest such cases?

Yes, and you already did it by asking the question meta.

As for the rejected edit: The reason given seems a bit strange. You cleaned the post and changed the title contentwise. I cannot judge the quality but I can say that it definitely became more specific which would be a good thing.

So provided that it makes sense this edit should definitely have been accepted. As a reviewer I would have needed to skip it due to lack of knowledge.

The reviewers who rejected the edit are well known members but probably a bit unexperienced in R judging by their tags. It may be that it was a misjudgement.

If someone confirms that the edit is sound, anyone >2k rep should just do it or you should submit it again.

These things happen. Here are only humans at work but most probably with only good intentions.

Answer (score 12):

On first glance, it looks like a review audit. I got hundreds of them so I know when I see one... or something that looks very similar.

The use of the word "Stargazer" in the title is the most intimating, it takes a while to notice it's actually being used as a tag and that you just moved it from the beginning to the end of the title.

Personally I would have approved after taking a second and third look, but can see the reviewers point of view as well.

Comment: Well, but if you see something like that in the title and you find it intimidating you should stop, reread, and think whether you should skip it, google for "stargazer" and see what it is, etc. etc. you don't reject the edit as spam!

Comment: @nico easy to say it now, but when you're at it, you sometimes forget to stop and take another look.

Comment: If they had given a different close reason I would agree with you, but before accusing someone of spamming I would definitely stop and think twice. And, maybe the first reviewer was fooled by the title, but the other two just clicked whatever the other had chosen without even thinking. This is exactly the type of behaviour that motivates audits...

Comment: Maybe there are not enough positive audits.. if the possibility of an audits biases reviewers to choose the negative outcome.

Comment: @Trilarion no positive audits for suggested edits at all, only bad.

Comment: @nico:  But do those reviewers really think the edit was deliberate vandalism/spamification?  That's a serious charge; how often does that sort of thing happen in real life?  How quick would the reviewers have been to choose that reason--or to reject the edit at all--if they didn't know about review audits?  I suspect audits are the main reason why they **didn't** "stop, reread, and think" in this case.

Comment: @Alan true, I agree the suggested edits audits cause more harm than good - they are way too easy to notice and as this case proves, cause false positives.

Comment: @ShadowWizard So, they're not as easy to notice as you thought they were, and when you see something that might be an audit, you should *still* pay attention. That's what the audits are for in the first place: forcing you to pay attention.

Comment: @hvd personally that's exactly what I'm doing, but can also understand how come others don't do it and that's what my answer is trying to say.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, by "you" I didn't mean you personally. :)

Comment: @nico Audits generally are vandalism and they look similar to this edit at a glance. So it's quite possible that the reviewer thought "Yet another of those annoying audits. => reject as vandalism".