# Contesting a rejected edit

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

I'm looking to contest a rejected edit, that was rejected by the OP on two separate occasions. One was via an overwrite by editing the answer, the second was done by the user as an actual rejection.

The first edit can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12515862).
The second edit can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12516259).

I attempted to improve the formatting and make the post more readable. In its current state, the spacing makes it a bit difficult to parse. I added some method formatting and other similar things. I was also removing possible sensitive information, as I don't think e-mails and names should be given out in such a question.

I saw [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286202/contest-rejected-edit) the best way to contest is to raise a question on meta. Do people agree with my edit, or was I removing necessary information with taking away the spaces? Is there something else I missed? Let me know if this isn't the place to raise this and what I should do instead.

Comment: There is now a [third attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12516489) in review.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Matt, was about to correct those bits, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I improved the edit a little and approved it. It was indeed a good edit to an otherwise not very readable question.

Comment: Thanks @Magisch, thought I was having a special moment there