# Why was my edit, which fixed obvious spelling errors, rejected?

Tags: support, edits, rejected-edits

I am puzzled why this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14536672) was rejected. I noticed two spelling errors which I corrected.  Maybe such things bother me more than others, but why reject the fix?

Comment: "initialisation" is not wrong

Comment: It was specifically rejected by the original author, so even if there was a way to "contest" "erroneously" rejected suggested edits (there isn't), this would be an exception. Obviously Angew wanted to maintain his British spelling of the word. Do note that [the general rule around here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of) is that you should not correct British English to American English, or vice versa. It makes our friends on the other side of the pond somewhat uppity. :-)

Comment: The larger intention of letting you edit posts before you have enough rep is to get you used to what is going to happen once you do get enough rep.  Users will disagree with your edits then too, complaining about it isn't going to accomplish anything either.  The zen is to not fret about it.

Comment: @yellowantphil in a regular expression, yes.

Comment: I am glad that I asked. It is good to be enlightened.  @HansPassant I wasn't complaining, just curious as to why.  Valid British spelling wasn't the reason given for rejecting the edit.  If it had said that then I wouldn't have posted my question here. You shouldn't imply motive when not in evidence.

Comment: *Valid British spelling wasn't the reason given for rejecting the edit.* - I think they have to pick from a list of reasons when rejecting an edit. There probably wasn't a matching reason.

Comment: @BSMP Thank you. Perhaps "OP's alternate spelling is correct" should be added to the list. I am exposed to some British spellings but clearly not all.

Comment: Don't vandalize your own post >:(

Comment: Two things: 1) When selecting "Reject and Edit", as your edit was, the reviewer doesn't select a reject reason. The reason given is a static reason. 2) Please do not vandilize (completely change to a pointless statement) your own post. No, you can't delete it right now, because of the answer, but you really don't need to. You have lost no reputation from this post. There is no reputation on Meta.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I am sorry that I got involved.

Comment: Also, re your edit, I highly doubt you've offended anyone with this post. It's been downvoted likely because people feel that your edit really shouldn't be accepted and was correctly rejected. That you didn't realize that was the British spelling does not change that it was okay to reject that edit. Voting on Meta is not necessarily dependent on the quality of your post, but can also be due to the voter's opinions of the premise of your post.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  And don't bother making edits that only fix a couple misspellings.  Save your edits for formatting or large problems.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 your edit seems to come from a mindset of "if someone downvotes me, he/she must be angry at me".... please don`t think like that... for your own sanity, if nothing else. Downvotes are all about your post and not about you at all. Here it could be that your initial description seems to argue that what happened wasn't okay, but the downvotes you get just indicate people disagree with you. I downvoted you and you didn't offend, irk, or irritate me. There is no need for a white flag or apologies.

Comment: @Patrice I view a down vote as indicating that the question is without merit. My question said that I was puzzled.  It didn't say that the rejection of my edit was unmerited, just that I didn't understand why it was rejected.  I knew that I was missing something and wanted to find out what that was so that I didn't repeat the error.  I have come to understand that my error was posting on meta which after this fiasco is an error that I will not repeat.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 error? Why is it an error? You asked your question and got your answer? The scores on meta don't matter at all.... why is it a problem you came here? No one was insulting or mean. You asked to get enlightened and this is what happened. On Meta downvote means different things is all. Do not take them personal. It's a surefire way to get aggravated on Stack... The question isn't without merit. The premise is wrong (and if you say you were just asking...The title says you want to contest a reject. I don't contest when I'm not sure I am right....that's what my vote was based off.)

Comment: @yellowtail Oh, I copied that! I did a search of meta for rejected edits and that came up. I wanted to ask the same question (why was my edit rejected). It said that I needed to post on meta. I copied the title but it wouldn't let me post with that same title so I added to the end of it.

Comment: I did a search of meta.stackoverflow for **rejected edit** and this came up first in the list [Q: Contesting a rejected edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324050/contesting-a-rejected-edit). I wasn't so focused on the "Contested" part even though if there wasn't a good reason I might have gone that way. I just wanted to find out how I could learn more. I guess I could have searched on "learn more about rejected edits".

Comment: @AaronHall Down voted and useful doesn't strike me as belonging in the same sentence.  If it is useful, why the down vote? Either the question is without merit or the down vote is without merit.

Comment: I can disagree with the premise of something and downvote based on that,  but the Q&A pair still contains useful information. The downvote tooltip doesn't JUST say "not useful"..

Comment: "The Black Hat is judgment - the devil's advocate or why something may not work. Spot the difficulties and dangers; where things might go wrong. Probably the most powerful and useful of the Hats but a problem if overused." You folks should learn to wear other [hats](http://www.debonogroup.com/six_thinking_hats.php) if only occasionally.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 no... you need to NOT TAKE IT PERSONALLY. Simple. That's always the major breakthrough for new users. Once they stop seeing downvotes as attack on them and tools to help monitor/moderate the site, that's when the site truly "clicks" for them. As long as you see downvotes as against you, you will hate your meta stack experience (and possibly your stack experience too). You get people telling you downvoting isn't what you say it is, and all you do is argue as if downvotes mean EXACTLY what you have said, when it's clearly been pointed out your premise is flawed...

Comment: @Patrice And how exactly did your down votes help the moderators monitor the site?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 by indicating the value of your question in terms of clarity, research, and our quality standards (+ the usual reasons on meta to downvote). The same way the whole network is determined. In what exactly do you see the downvotes as an attack would be the better question here though.

Comment: Question was clear, or at least with the changed title it is. I did research which is why I knew to post it. Quality? Hmmm. I think not. I think that you all are too quick to put on the black hat and shoot. My hypothesis is the lack of the milk of human kindness. Is that meta enough for you?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 sure.... think what you will. I downvoted because when I first saw your question it was sporting a false premise, so that is why I downvoted. Others downvoted for whatever reason they chose (among the couple already explained to you). Continue thinking the whole site is against you and out to get you... that'll fare well. If the whole site was so "black hat" as you say, would you have gotten an answer? no. Would people have commented to explain to you how your premises are flawed and in what way? no. Think what you will if you don't want to see it. Have fun, I'm done.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Point to me the kind of language that warranted the insult? YOU GOT YOUR ANSWER..... why are you still fighting? The intent of Stack is to build a repo of knowledge so that the NEXT person with your question can find help. Same on meta. Your question is important in THAT sense. Removing it means next time someone searches for your scenario, we'll get another rant and fight (for no reason).... isn't it better to bypass all that by leaving the answer on the site?  (and you DID understand the actions, so insulting the community that answered your question isn't appropriate here)

Comment: When I corrected the "false premise" did you reverse your down vote? I only down vote a question if it is egregious.  I do offer corrective advice.  You folks down vote as a first response. I was simply asking for an explanation which I got. You send a terrible message to new comers by over using the down vote.  Compound that to fact that I was questioning a mod's action. One can certainly question the down vote as being more akin to "how dare he" then "He should improve the quality". Especially when you don't tell me till questioned why you down voted. I view your down vote as unfriendly.

Comment: And don't sweat it. I have petitioned to have my account removed from meta.

Comment: Mike, I am very sorry that you've received such a bad reception here on Meta. I literally have no explanation for why that might have happened. I confess that I didn't read all of the comments, but the question that you asked was eminently reasonable and presented in a respectable way, which is really all we ask. Sure, you clearly goofed here, but you did it with pure intentions and because you honestly didn't know better. That happens to all of us. I'm not trying to convince you not to have this question dissociated from your account or whatever, I'm just saying I'm sorry about what happened.

Comment: I'm just sad I can't propose an edit to this post to change "puzzled" to "pussled".

Answer (score 16):

> initialisation

is just the British spelling, where Americans would write

> initialization

There's no semantical difference between them whatsoever.

When editing, please keep the [version of English used by the OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us). Yes, you fixed the other typo, but this should help you understand why the OP single-handledly rejected the edit.

Comment: To the OPs credit, I didn't know that was the British spelling. The OP just might not have realized that was the case and was "correcting" it because it looks wrong. (Your answer's still correct, just pointing out it's not always so simple to know that it's a difference in the versions of English. If it's a word you don't see the British spelling of often, it might not click right away.)

Comment: @Kendra I set my browser spell checker to accept British and American spelling after I unknowingly "corrected" some British spelling once.

Comment: @yellowantphil That's a good idea, especially if you're mostly on international sites like the Stack Exchange network. :)

Comment: Kendra and @yellowtail. Thank you. I just changed my google chrome browser to spell check both English (American) and English (United Kingdom).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 you can flag your post for moderators to delete... but it likely will be rejected as there is absolutely nothing wrong with the question (maybe title now can be edited to include "spelling of initialisation", but that totally optional).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 in my opinion, this Q&A pair is certainly valuable to future readers. If even veterans like Kendra indicate they didn't know about this spelling difference ... You can [request to disassociate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request) the question from your account via the 'contact us' form.

Comment: @Glorfindel Off topic, but that you consider me a veteran is a high compliment to my mind. Thank you for that. :)

Comment: UK English and US English are both wrong when discussing C++, the correct spelling of formal C++ language productions is the one found IN THE C++ STANDARD.  The Standard documents discuss "list initialization" at great length, while they never even mention "list initialisation" (things like "listing initialization" are also wrong).  The edit was correct, the intent is to discuss the specific behavior of C++ "list initialization" by its correct name, not some sort-of-descriptive made-up term.

Comment: If what you're saying is true, @Ben, it would be literally impossible to have localized versions of Stack Overflow. Except when they're directly quoting from the standard, I'm pretty sure that Portuguese Stack Overflow uses the Portuguese translation of "list initialization". Do you really think people are confused about what they mean?

Answer (score -6):

It's surreal that people are fighting over spellings in different human languages, when the term in question doesn't come from any human language, it comes from the C++ Standard.

Subsection 8.6.4 is titled "List-initialization".  The first sentence gives a definition for "list-initialization", and it appears several dozen times throughout the document.  There is absolutely no meaning given to "initialisation", it doesn't even appear in the document.

When you mean to talk about a formally specified concept, please use the exact term that appears in the specification, not some approximation.  Don't say "mold" when you mean "cast".  Don't say "bequest" when talking about "inheritance".  Or "object creation" when you mean "construction".  Or "pattern" for "template".  The vocabulary for computer science is different from either US English or UK English.

Comment: Please note that I'm not against having UK English and US English equally acceptable for prose (y'know, the actual explanations).  It's the technical terms that MUST be used as they appear in the specification.

Comment: if editor wanted to convince reviewers that overriding original spelling is justified by C++ Standard they would better explain that in [meta-tag:edit-summary]

Comment: @gnat: I do agree,

Comment: Well that's just ridiculous to say it originated in the C++ standard. It's an English word first and foremost. Just because the standard used a different spelling than that of British English, doesn't mean it's now a new word.

Comment: @Rob: Its etymology traces back through English to Latin initiālis, but neither the English nor Latin words are being used in that answer, rather the C++ technical term, which is defined (spelling, meaning, usage, etc) by the C++ Standard, not by any dictionary.

Comment: Not an unreasonable answer, but I don't find it convincing. To this non-native speaker, the fact that the standard was written in American English seems arbitrary. If this was a question from Stack Overflow-in-Portuguese, it would use "inicialização de listas". Replacing the Portugusese translation with the original English expression wouldn't be reasonable. At most, "list-initialization" might be used parenthetically if there was a real need to make a precise reference to the standard subsection. I don't see why a scenario involving British English shouldn't be handled in the same manner.

Comment: @duplode: Well, in a context where the readers wouldn't benefit from the English roots of the term, it certainly would make sense to accompany it with a descriptive phrase.... but at that point, I would expect to other equally valid descriptions (the translation of "braced initializer" perhaps) about as commonly.  And the term isn't "a precise reference to the subsection", but to the concept defined in the Standard, and yes, when referring to that concept you do need to use the exact name.  We come across people all the time who try to redefine terms, and it just isn't helpful.