# Can I get a second opinion on a rejected edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

It would seem the proper way to ask for a second review on an already rejected edit would be to post in meta, at least that's the impression I got from reading this:

[Contest rejected edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286202/contest-rejected-edit)

If this is not the proper way, or if there's any better way please tell me.

As for the edit that was rejected, please have a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12722901

All I really did was correctly format the HTML and JS code - only the order has changed by doing so - but I guess that's related to how SO handles the Code Snippet window.

So the question is: How can I get an already rejected edit back into the review process (w/o creating a new edit)?

Update: As stated in the comments, I will not attempt in doing so, if the person who rejected the edit is the author.

Comment: Note that it was actually rejected by the post's author, perhaps they didn't understand what you were doing.

Comment: Oh, right, I did not notice. So I guess there's no use in creating a new edit. I still wonder if it's possible to get a rejected edit back into the review process without creating a new edit.

Comment: Even if you did so there's nothing to stop the post's author from rejecting it again.

Comment: @RobertLongson that's why I said that it's probably no use in this case. I'd still like to know if/how it's possible in the future, in case the person who rejects the edit is not the author.

Comment: You could comment, explaining what the edit does, rather than such a substantial-looking change coming "out of the blue". Include a link to e.g. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/. The edit itself seems fine.

Comment: I would have rejected your edit as well.  There's no need to [convert code to a snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271597/250725).  If you had just adjusted the formatting, and left it as a code block, it would have been a better edit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'll make sure of it in the future. I admit I was lazy and wanted to make use of the snippet window's `Tidy` feature. My goal was to improve the readability, but you're right, there was no need for a snippet.